# Is Paul speaking of the same group in Philippians 1 and 3?

Tags: paul, philippians

Yesterday I've asked a question in regards to the identity of "the dogs" in Philippians 3 - [Who are "those dogs"?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/76695/27054)

This current question now aims to understand the relationship between "the dogs" and the one's who "preach Christ from envy and rivalry" in Philippians 1:15‭-‬18 ESV

> Some indeed **preach Christ from envy and rivalry**, but others from good will. The latter do it out of love, knowing that I am put here for the defense of the gospel. **The former proclaim Christ out of selfish ambition, not sincerely but thinking to afflict me in my imprisonment**. What then? Only that in every way, whether in pretense or in truth, Christ is proclaimed, and in that I rejoice. Yes, and I will rejoice,

Are they the same group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two entirely different groups (though some interpreters link the two):

- Phil 3:2 = the dogs who demand circumcision are the ones trying to gain salvation by the works of the flesh, ie, are Judaizers and do not understand the gospel of grace.
- Phil 1:15-18 = preachers who preach Christ from envy, that is, they preach the gospel of Christ to gain status, or get a following.

Benson says this:

> Php 1:15-17. Some indeed preach Christ even of envy — Envying my
> success, or envying me that esteem and reputation which I have in the
> church, and seeking to gain it to themselves; and strife — Striving to
> draw people off from approving me to applaud themselves, and being
> desirous to maintain in the church a party that shall oppose me, and
> willing to add as many abetters to it as they possibly can.

Barnes suggests this:

> Some indeed preach Christ even of envy and strife - What was the
> ground of this "envy and strife" the apostle does not mention. It
> would seem, however, that even in Rome there was a party which was
> jealous of the influence of Paul, and which supposed that this was a
> good opportunity to diminish his influence, and to strengthen their
> own cause. He was not now at large so as to be able: to meet and
> confute them. They had access to the mass of the people. It was easy,
> under plausible pretences, to insinuate hints about the ambitious
> aims, or improper influence of Paul, or to take strong ground against
> him and in favor of their own views, and they availed themselves of
> this opportunity.

It is certainly possible that of these preachers of envy were envious of Paul and aghast at the loss of the Levitical law; but I believe that the story was more than this.  The Cambridge commentary correctly observes:

> Not that the Judaizer of the Pharisaic type was his only adversary
> within the Church. He had also, very probably, to face an opposition
> of a “libertine” type, a distortion of his own doctrine of free grace
> (Romans 6:1, &c., and below, Php 3:18-19); and again an opposition of
> the mystic, or gnostic, type, in which Jewish elements of observance
> were bent with an alien theosophy and angelology (see the Ep. to the
> Colossians). But ch. Php 3:1-9 fixes the reference here to Christians
> of the type of Acts 15:1.